# How can I make 'string' to array true?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, sorting

let's say we are given a list of lowercase strings,

I want a function to return a list with the strings sorted in alphabetical order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' at the beginning of the list.

`['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']`

Comment: Please add what language your using like python or java, and also please provide us with the code you tried.

Comment: And also your questions title and its content differ to a great extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```
words = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']    
custom_sort_order = ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z']
words = sorted(words, key=lambda word: [custom_sort_order.index(c) for c in word])
print(words)
```